# Ошибка синтаксиса, которую я не могу найти. Python

Tags: python, syntax

```py
def train(msg):{
    temp = input('Введите фразу\n:: '),
    msg[temp] = input('Введите ответ на данную фразу\n:: '),
    print('Записываю полученные данные в json файл...'),
    json.dump(msg,open('msg.json','w')),
    print('Полученные данные успешно записаны!'),
    return msg
}
```

[image: Вылезает вот такая ошибка invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: так там просто подтверждение того, что у меня вылезает ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне нет фигурных скобок, как большинстве языков. Тут используются отступы. То есть, Ваш код должен быть где то такой

```
def train(msg):
    temp = input('Введите фразу\n:: '),
    msg[temp] = input('Введите ответ на данную фразу\n:: '),
    print('Записываю полученные данные в json файл...'),
    json.dump(msg,open('msg.json','w')),
    print('Полученные данные успешно записаны!'),
    return msg
```

(Правда я не уверен, что теперь код стал совсем правильный, но выглядит более-менее)

Comment: У меня есть отступы в самом редакторе. Тут просто так копировалось)

Comment: А скобочки мне просто нравятся, да и компилятор не ругался на них

Comment: Вау, и правда без скобок заработало) Спасибо большое)

Comment: Такой у питона синтаксис. У питона нет компилятора, поэтому он не может ругаться

Comment: @Dazezh Питон не ругался, потому что сами по себе фигурные скобочки в нём допустимы - они применяются при описании словаря, либо множества. Питон подумал, что вы описываете словарь, но синтаксис у словаря всё-равно другой и как только питон нашёл место, где синтаксис не вписывается в словарь, тут то он и отругался.